# Get records only if all have specific status in SQL

Tags: sql

Tables `A` and `C` are linked through table `B`.

Table **A**:

| a_id | a_status |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | in progress |
| 2 | in progress |
| 3 | complete |
| 4 | complete |
| 5 | complete |
| 6 | complete |

Table **B**:

| c_id | a_id |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 3 |
| 101 | 4 |
| 101 | 5 |
| 104 | 6 |
| 104 | 2 |

I need to get `c_id` values from table `B` only if all records `a_status` is `complete`.

In this example, I would expect only item `101` because all the `a_id` records it is referenced to are complete.

I tried this query, but it returns any item with the complete status.

```
SELECT c_id
FROM b
WHERE a_id IN (
    SELECT a_id
    FROM a 
    WHERE status = "complete"
    GROUP BY a_id
    HAVING COUNT(b.c_id) = COUNT(*)
)
```

Is this possible in SQL what I am trying to do?

Comment: Remove the `where`. Test `having max(status) = 'complete'`

Comment: `"complete"` is read as a column named complete. Use single quotes for string literals, i.e. `'complete'`.

Comment: @shawnt00, unfortunately, no changes

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: @jarlh, 1) string is used for example, actually, there is an integer value. 2) I expect only one item - 101

Comment: I think you're also wanting to group by `c_id` rather than `a_id` so you'll have to do a join inside the subquery.

Comment: Or just use this if you only want the id values: `select c_id from B b inner join A a on a.a_id = b.a_id group by b.c_id having count(*) = count(case when a.a_status = 'completed' then 1 end)`

Comment: @shawnt00, cool, that works. Will experiment with different data and let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@shawnt00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322268/shawnt00) for the solution:

```
SELECT c_id from B b
INNER JOIN A a on a.a_id = b.a_id 
GROUP BY b.c_id 
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(CASE WHEN a.a_status = 'complete' THEN 1 END)
```

Comment: The query in you 'answer' is not returning results? see: https://dbfiddle.uk/2drKZuQR

Comment: @Luuk, There was a typo in the answer ('completed' instead of 'complete'). Fixed. Thanks!